# Block users using their ip addresses in php

Tags: php

Actually I have no any practical experience using `php` other than in  locally hosted server. I am following a video tutorial to learn `php`, and there was this code to block specific `ip` from a web site. The thing I want to know here if this is works for users who have dynamic ip addresses also or not? And, is this a proper way to block a user? I'm so glad if you can explain more about practical side of blocking users. Thank you!

```
<?php  
$http_client_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$http_x_forwarded_for = $SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote_address = $SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (!empty($http_client_ip)){
   $ip_address = $http_client_ip;
} elseif (!empty($http_x_forwarded_for)) {
   $ip_address = $http_x_forwarded_for;
} else {
   $ip_address = $remote_address;
}

//block list contains all the IPs that should be blocked.
foreach ($block_list as $block) {
  if ($block == $ip_address){
    die();
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: No, what this does is getting the users current IP and comparing it to the blocklist (an over complicated one if I may add)

Comment: die(); is used to kill the page, right?

Comment: Yes, it is. How are you going to address multiple users using 1 ip due to NAT? Don't bother with this, it's trivial to spoof an IP and get around your blacklist. You will need a user login system to reliably track and optionally block users.

Comment: If you have to block an IP address, doing it at the web server level is the correct way to do it (as the answer below from Chandu suggests.) As an educational point, your foreach loop would be much more efficient if rewritten as `if(in_array($ip_address, $block_list)) { die(); }`

Answer (score 3):

Visitors can be restricted from accessing your site by using the IP deny manager in your cPanel or by adding the Allow or Deny code in your .htaccess file.
The syntax is as follows:

```
Allows IP 122.102.1.2 access to your website.

Allow from 122.102.1.2

Denys IP 25.122.6.3 access to your website.

Deny from 25.122.6.3
```

both combined as,

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 203.25.45.2
Deny from unwanted-domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

No it does not. It takes his IP and check if it is in the block list. As soon as it will change, he won't be blocked anymore.

You could try blocking a larger range of IP.
By example:

```
 $targetAddr = "123.123..*..*";  //yes is two dots

//this code will match any class of 123.123.x.x, 
//you can also do "123.123.123..*" to do anything that is 123.123.123.x

if (ereg($targetAddr, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    //remote address match, do something or don't do anything
} else {
   //do whatever you want to address that doesn't match
}
```

To be honest I don't think this is the best way to block users. This could block other users than the one you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would be best for regional block, when you want to block your site from a certain geographical area, using the IP range assigned to that area. as goes for certain users with dynamic IP addresses, it won't work well.